# HA Cloud SQL writes low latency despite synchronous replication across multiple DCs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have just read Google's Cloud SQL's high availability [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability).

From what I understood in order for Google to:

- Guarantee no data loss in case of primary node failure.
- Allow clients to use standby node as read replica with strong consistency.

Google has to replicate writes in a **synchronous** way across multiple zones.

This seems like a very costly operation that should affect write transactions' latency. I however personally have not observed any significant latency differences between HA and non-HA version of GCP's Postgres.

How is it possible?

Comment: Maybe your observations are just not very sensitive to this issue.  Since you didn't describe what they actually are, what more can we say?

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but i hope it helps anyway.

The technology used here is the same that is used for regional persistent disks, which are highly optimized for these kind of multi-zone write scenarios. This basically means that the operation is costly but not as costly as you seem to expect. However even Google itself acknowledges the fact that there will be increased write latency. From a page directly linked from the documentation you shared:

> Regional persistent disks are an option when write performance is less critical than data redundancy across multiple zones.
> [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance_2)

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing Read Replicas, [HA](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability) and [Legacy HA](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#legacy_mysql_high_availability_option).

Cloud SQL some time ago was using [Legacy HA](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/high-availability#legacy_mysql_high_availability_option) which uses an explicit instance that replicates from the primary instance (in some way it is a read replica). In this particular case there could be replication lag because as you mention, the writes are synchronous and the performance could be impacted.

Legacy HA it is only available for [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-legacy-ha).

In the case of Postgres it is expect you do not see a difference between HA and non-HA because in fact Postgres does not use this Legacy HA and uses the current HA schema which uses a single Regional Disk. non-HA also uses a single disk, the difference is that the disk is Zonal.

In other words, both (HA and non-HA) use a single disk, what changes is the scope of the disk (Regional or Zonal).

Finally since it is only a disk, there's no need to replicate like in a Read Replica or Legacy HA.